# Relation between RDD and Dataset/Dataframe from a technical point of view

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to understand if there is a relationship between RDDs and Dataframes/Datesets from a technical point of view. RDDs are often described as the fundamental data abstraction in Spark. In my understanding this would mean that Dataframes/Datasets should also be based on it.  In the original [Spark SQL Paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/matei/papers/2015/sigmod_spark_sql.pdf) the figures 1 & 3 point to this connection. However, I haven't found any documentation on how this connection looks like (if it exists at all).

So my question: Are Dataframes/Datasets based on RDDs or are these two concepts independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataframe and Datasets are based on the Rdd, however this is a little bit hidden. The fact is that Dataframe and Datasets are more used on the spark-sql project, where as Rdd are on the spark-core.

Here is the technical point of view on how Dataframe, which is Dataset[Row], and Rdd are linked: Dataframe has a `QueryExecution`  which controls how all the sql execution acts. Now when this get executed by the engine it will be output in an internal rdd of type Row,  `lazy val toRdd: RDD[InternalRow] = executedPlan.execute()`. Having that rdd and a schema it will form a Dataframe.